# Windows Terminal - PowerShell customization via oh-my-posh/posh-git Set-Theme error?

Tags: git, powershell, windows-terminal

**Windows Terminal - PowerShell customization via oh-my-posh/posh-git Set-Theme error?**

I follow the exact tutorial of Microsoft link: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup), video link: [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/lu__oGZVT98)

I have installed Posh-Git and Oh-My-Posh: via this code -

> Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser

> Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser

I have installed PSReadLine: via this code -

> Install-Module -Name PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser -Force -SkipPublisherCheck

I am also created Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file by typing- **code $PROFILE**, in my PowerShell profile and copy/paste this code:

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-Theme Paradox
```

But I get this error:
[image]

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/error/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 31):

`Set-Theme` is an *oh-my-posh* V2 cmdlet; you're likely running V3. Provided you followed the rest of the setup correctly, you can simply replace `Set-Theme Paradox` with `Set-PoshPrompt -Theme Paradox`.

More info here: https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/windows#update

Comment: CoolBots, thanks for the perfect answer. Upvote.
@Nihal Towfiq , I think you need to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

0. First, ensure that you are using an **administrative shell** and install with powershell.exe (or Windows Terminal)
1. Install *Powershell Get*. [Powershell Get MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7.1)

> The PowerShell Gallery is the central repository for PowerShell content. In it, you can find useful PowerShell modules containing PowerShell commands and Desired State Configuration (DSC) resources.

```
Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
```

2. Install *PS Readline* [PS Readline GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine)

> This module replaces the command line editing experience of PowerShell for versions 3 and up. It provides: Syntax coloring; Simple syntax error and more (watch link upside)

```
Install-Module PSReadLine
```

3. Now, changes your executions policies to `Bypass`. Read more [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1)

> An execution policy is part of the PowerShell security strategy. Execution policies **determine whether you can load configuration files**, such as your PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

3.1 Check your execution policy:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

4. Finally, try or reinstall your **oh-my-posh**. Link oh-my-posh [here](http://Install-Module%20oh-my-posh%20-Scope%20AllUsers%20Import-Module%20oh-my-posh)

```
Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope AllUsers
```

and before replace your existing prompt

> Edit `$PROFILE` in your preferred PowerShell version and add the following line. Autocompletion is available so it will loop through all available themes.

4.1 if you have [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

```
Code $PROFILE
```

4.2 and write

```
Set-PoshPrompt -Theme 'posh-theme-here'
```